# Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit install with Win 7-64 - no OS found

Tags: installation, windows-7

I attempted to install Ubuntu 13.04 with Windows 7 64 bit on an HP DV7t-7000 notebook. The Ubuntu installer was unable to identify the existing Windows installation. I have two hard drives installed and I think it did not even see the first one possibly because it is GUID and the notebook is using UEFI.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue which I fixed with boot-repiar:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair  
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair
$ boot-repair
```

I have Ubuntu Raring + Windows8 both working fine.

Good luck.